# Make EditText get input from NumberPicker

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to make an EditText field that onClick opens a numberPicker so the user can input a number.
this is my code:

```
tipET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getContext());
            numberPicker.setMaxValue(1000);
            numberPicker.setMinValue(0);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setView(numberPicker);
            builder.setTitle("tip");
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "TIP NUMBER IS:" + numberPicker.getValue());
                            num =  numberPicker.getValue();
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            builder.create();
            builder.show();

      }
    });
    tipET.setText(String.valueOf(num));
```

for some reason tipET text stays the same after i input another number, why is that?

also for the first time i click on the EditText the keyboard pops up, and only on the second click my NumberPicker opens, how can i prevent that?

Comment: Add `tipET.setText(String.valueOf(num));` to the `onClick` method for the positive button, right below `num = numberPicker.getValue();` and try it... Where have you declared `num`? Is it a class attribute?

Comment: Thank you! stupid mistake..

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it, for the sake of completeness ;-) Accept it and you get a little reputation, too

Answer (score 0):

Add `tipET.setText(String.valueOf(num));` to the onClick method for the positive button, right below `num = numberPicker.getValue();`, like this:

```
tipET.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getContext());
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(1000);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setView(numberPicker);
        builder.setTitle("tip");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "TIP NUMBER IS:" + numberPicker.getValue());
                        num =  numberPicker.getValue();
                        // update the text of the EditText here
                        tipET.setText(String.valueOf(num));
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();

  }
});
```